# Loop over li elements, check class and set css

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

Hi there I have a problem with a jquery function. I have a account menu on my wordpress site. I want to set the opacity to 1 of the element who has the class `is-active` (the visible menu entry). When I click on a specific element (bsp: My Orders) it gets the class name `is-active` is active but the problem is that the opacity dont change. When I click on another element (bsp: My Account) the last one (My Orders) which I clicked change the opacity (but to late). This is so crazy and I dont have any idea.

My HTML Code:

```html
<ul>
 <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--dashboard is-active active">
  <a href="https://mywebsite.com/en/my-account/" style="opacity: 0.5;" data-loaded="true">My Account</a> <!--This should be opacity: 1 because of is-active-->
 </li>
 <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--subscriptions">
  <a href="https://mywebsite.com/en/my-account/subscriptions/" style="opacity: 0.5;">Subscriptions</a>
 </li>
 <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--orders active"> 
  <a href="https://mywebsite.com/en/my-account/orders/" style="opacity: 1;" data-loaded="true">My Orders</a> <!--This should be opacity: .5-->
 </li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link').each(function(i, obj) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
     var myaccountlink = $(this).attr('class');
     myaccountlink = myaccountlink.replace(/\s+/g, '.');
     $('.' + myaccountlink).find('a').css('opacity', '1', '!important');
    } else {
     $(this).find('a').css('opacity', '.5');
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: How is this PHP related?

Comment: where is the click function?

Comment: Please post the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove inline rules for opacity and apply css based on classes

```css
li{
  opacity:0.5;
  }
li.active{
  opacity:1;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
     <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--dashboard is-active active">
      <a href="https://mywebsite.com/en/my-account/"  data-loaded="true">My Account</a> <!--This should be opacity: 1 because of is-active-->
     </li>
     <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--subscriptions">
      <a href="https://mywebsite.com/en/my-account/subscriptions/" >Subscriptions</a>
     </li>
     <li class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--orders active"> 
      <a href="https://mywebsite.com/en/my-account/orders/"  data-loaded="true">My Orders</a> <!--This should be opacity: .5-->
     </li>
    </ul>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link').each(function(i, obj) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
     var myaccountlink = $(this).attr('class');
     myaccountlink = myaccountlink.replace(/\s+/g, '.');
     $('.' + myaccountlink).find('a').css('opacity', '1', '!important');
    } else {
     $(this).find('a').css('opacity', '.5');
    }
 });
});
```